# Click function inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to loop my .hide() and .show() click handlers and I can't get this simple part to work correctly. My buttons are called "#towelcome" etc. I'm assuminig I'm missing something stupid and obvious. All of the divs are hidden in css.

```
var elements = ["welcome", "slides", "projects", "pages"];
for (i=0;i<=elements.length-1;i++){ 
    $("#to"+elements[i]).click(function() {
      $("#"+elements[i]).show();
    });
}
```

/UPDATE:------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following code is the code I am trying to minify.

```
$("#toprojects").click(function(){
    $("#projects").show();
    $("#slides").hide();
    $("#pages").hide();
    $("#welcome").hide();
});

$("#toslides").click(function(){
    $("#projects").hide();
    $("#slides").show();
    $("#pages").hide();
    $("#welcome").hide();
});

$("#topages").click(function(){
    $("#projects").hide();
    $("#slides").hide();
    $("#pages").show();
    $("#welcome").hide();
});

if(window.location.hash === "#slides"){
    $("#projects").hide();
    $("#slides").show();
    $("#pages").hide();
    $("#welcome").hide();
}

if(window.location.hash === "#projects"){
    $("#projects").show();
    $("#slides").hide();
    $("#pages").hide();
    $("#welcome").hide();
}

if(window.location.hash === "#pages"){
    $("#projects").hide();
    $("#slides").hide();
    $("#pages").show();
    $("#welcome").hide();
}
```

found a related post here and it solved it pretty nicely
[jQuery: Set click from array loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494161/jquery-set-click-from-array-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think something along these lines should work for you:

```
var elements = ["welcome", "slides", "projects", "pages"];

var clickHandler = function(element) {
    var id = element.attr('id') || $(this).attr('id');

    $.each(elements, function(index, value) {
        var element = $('#' + value);
        if (id !== 'to' + element.attr('id')) {
            element.hide();
        } else {
            element.show();
        }
    });    
};

$.each(elements, function(index, value) {
    $('#to' + value).click(clickHandler);
});

if ($.inArray(window.location.hash, elements)) {
    var id = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    clickHandler($('#' + id));
}
```

Comment: `.each` is a JQuery method, so it won't work on `elements` unless you wrap it in a `$()`. I don't think there was anything wrong with the original loop anyway.

Comment: I think you mean `$.each(elements, function(index, value) { /*..*/ }`, no?

Comment: You are right that there is nothing to gain from using each, just cleaner code is all. That's why for performance I would recommend the second approach.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why this `, len = elements.length; i < len;` and not `; i < elements.length;`?

Comment: It is a performance optimization. By caching the value of length, we do not re-evaluate the length every iteration of the loop. It is considered a best practice by many front-end engineers.

Comment: I like efficiency, as much as the next guy, thanks. I think I need the for loop, please look at the updates to the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
var elements = ["welcome", "slides", "projects", "pages"];
jQuery.each(elements,function(){ 
element = this;
    $("#to"+element).live("click",function() {
      $("#"+element).show(); //  use toggle for hiding/show as per current state

    });
});
```

Comment: i set jQuery.each(elements, function(index, element) { and it works

Answer (score 1):

We need to see more of your code to be sure, but the obvious things that might be missing are:

1. You're using JQuery functionality here: have you included the jQuery library in your page?
2. The code above needs to be run after the document has fully loaded, otherwise the click() event may not get registered to the button properly. The best way to do this is to use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` method. Simply wrap all the above code inside the `$(document).ready() {}` function, and it should work.

You also need to pass the `i` variable into the click function, as it won't actually get called until later, and the original value of `i` will have long since disappeared by then.

```
$(document).ready() {
    var elements = ["welcome", "slides", "projects", "pages"];
    for (i=0;i<=elements.length-1;i++){ 
        $("#to"+elements[i]).click(function(i) {
            $("#"+elements[i]).show();
        });
    }
}
```

As others have suggested, you could refactor the loop to use `.each()`, but I don't see any point in that. I might have used `for(i in elements) {...}` instead, but the syntax you've used is fine.

Comment: var i inside the click function is [object Object]

Comment: everything is connected and wrapped in doc.ready it also needs to be $(document).ready(function() { no?

Comment: @Thomas - yes, you're right; I typed it up in a hurry. But you get what I was trying to say at least. In any case, having seen your edits to the question, I think there's a better solution than any of the answers have given so far (including mine), so I've posted an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into an issue with **closure**. The value of `i`, regardless of which element is clicked, will be `4`. There are many ways around it, but jQuery offers a particularly convenient one, the `each` function:

```
var elements = ["welcome", "slides", "projects", "pages"];
$.each(elements, function(index, element) {
    $("#to" + element).click(function() {
        $("#" + element).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think I need the for loop, please look at the updates to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your updates with the code you're 'trying to minify', I think a different approach may work just as well. Using the JQuery `toggle()` function and some class names as well as the IDs, you can put the whole thing into a few lines, without needing a loop at all. Something like this:

```
$(".to-button").click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^to/,'');
    $(".infopanel").hide();
    $("#"+name).show();
});
```

Then your HTML code would have classes like so:

```
<div id='toprojects' class='to-button'>Projects</div>
```

and

```
<div id='projects' class='infopanel'>info about projects here...</div>
```

and similarly for slides, pages and welcome.

I was trying to come up with a way to combine the `hide()` and `show()` lines into one using `.toggle()` with the `showorhide` flag, but it's too early in the morning to be thinking too hard.  ;-)   I'm sure there is a way though.